# Rails Route URL segment with + (plus) sign character in id is not parsed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a TagsController class, with a route like the following (in routes.rb)

```
resources :tags
```

Now, when I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/test
```

It works correctly.

However, when I go to

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/c++
```

Rails seems to be parsing the "c++" as "c ", so this results in a "404 Not Found"

Could anyone give me any instructions on how I could fix this?

Comment: How did you set the route in `routes.rb`? I just tried `get 'tags/c++' => 'items#new'` in a test app and it works fine. *edit: But I'm using Rails 4... dunno if that matters.

Comment: Are "test" and "c++" IDs/slugs of `Test`? More details of your setup? I tried "c++" as slug with FriendlyID and it worked fine. What makes you think Rails isn't parsing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For rails 4 rails provides constrain options to determine regex parameter in routes:

This is constrains for allowing you to access param with `/photos/1` or `/photos/RR27`

```
resources :tags, constraints: { id: /[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]+/ }
```

For advance constraint

> By default the :id parameter doesn't accept dots - this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within an :id add a constraint which overrides this - for example
>   id: /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

```
resources :tags, constraints: { id: /[^\/]+/ }
```

These is the details of [specifying constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) routes. I hope it can help you.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Not sure why it was downvoted. Fixed my issue perfectly.

Comment: If you want to use a field other than id, e.g `resources :tags, param: :name`, you have to constrain that field rather than id, eg `resources :tags, param: :name, constraints: { name: /[^\/]+/ }`